# Sendgrid api marketing contacts v3 error access forbidden

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I had use follow https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact and set full permission for api key but the response:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"access forbidden. please ensure you have the correct scopes defined. see https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/API_Keys/api_key_permissions_list.html"}]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the API key correctly? What is the code you are using to make the API request?

Comment: yes i had set full permission for the API key, i had check the scopes too

Comment: I meant setting it in your code correctly?

Comment: yes my code correctly, and you can test in this link: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact
it response same error with my code

Comment: Can you try creating a new API key and see what happens with that?

Comment: ok i will try a new API key

Comment: sr i must to asked customer then can create a new API key. I just test with new API key full permission and still error

Comment: So you’re not creating this key yourself?

Comment: no i creating this key by myself

Comment: Is your account suspended for some reason? Have you contacted SendGrid support?

Comment: i still not contact sendgrid, but other api work normal, just just api error

Comment: If the issue is with your API key and your account, then it can’t be solved on Stack Overflow and you should contact SendGrid support.